# Sharepoint Custom Form Input box Autocomplete Sharepoint List

Tags: list, custom-list, search-results

I  have a Sharepoint List named ListName, i am the admin of the site so i have full permissions. I have created a content web editor with my own html file inside, the code is below. I want to when i type in a name, it searches the sharepoint list column "SuggestedName" and shows all the recommendations using Jquery Autocomplete, no box currently shows and annoyingly it takes ages for one letter to type.

The errors are:

> - Cannot read property 'find'
> - Maximum call stack size reached
> - SP.UI.UIUtility.isSvgNode is not a function

But I am not sure if these are actually relative.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script><script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/SP.Core.JS"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('poo').title = 'Test';
$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "ListName", //The name of your List
    sourceColumn: "SuggestedName", //The name of the column you are taking the data FROM
    columnName: "Test", // The name of the column/textbox you want to apply the Autocomplete TO
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 50,
    debug: true
});
});

</script> <input type="text" id="poo" title="Test" name="">
```

Answer (score 1):

This release of `"/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.js"` will not work as expected with custom forms!

**Instead, Try to use**

`jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js` with `jquery-1.8.2.js` that should work with the default and the custom form but you will face an issue with the required field.

Comment: What is the issue i will face with the required field?

Comment: will not work!!

Comment: Can you please tell me why it won't work and propose an alternative to autocomplete

Comment: It's by design, based on my experience, I tried this and it's not worked. also, I read a comment from SPServices author who said that.